# Client connection with remote Hbase server in case of network issue for some time

Tags: java, multithreading, hbase

I am using Table interface Interface( https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Table.html ) and using connection interface (  https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Connection.html ) to get the Table object. But as mention in Connection interface link,"**Connection creation is a heavy-weight operation. Connection implementations are thread-safe, so that the client can create a connection once, and share it with different threads.**".

So if I am creating a single connection object for all threads(creating this object in static block), so what will happen if there will be some network issue and client lost connection with hbase cluster for some time. Will the Connection object will still work after that ?

Comment: Hi there, I wonder if you figured this out? I tested on single thread and the connection seems to be working if it was lost and came back up again. If you have done other experiments I would love to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection is lost and come back again untill some certain period(**TCP Timeout**), everything will work fine.

As there is TCP connection established between client and hbase. Also as mentioned in the documentation, *"The individual connections to servers, meta cache, zookeeper connection, etc are all shared by the Table and Admin instances obtained from this connection"*, if we have sent the data while the network was unreachable, the data will be present in the buffer and client will try to do retransmissions of that segment, and hbase will get it when network will come back.

But if the network will not become reachable untill certain period(TCP Timeout), then TCP finally gives up and will close the socket.For this situation you have to put some catch block to handle this or need to restart the jar.